# I cannot populate an array with sql query data to export it as json object in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am new with php, I try to call the following function in order to populate an array of previously inserted data in mysql, but I get null.

```
function GetBusiness($con, $email) 
 {    
    $query = "SELECT * from Business WHERE B_EMAIL ='".$email."'";    
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$query); 
    $result_arr = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
        {
             $result_arr[] = $row;
        }
    return $result_arr;
}
```

and then I try to construct my json object as..

```
$result_business = array();
$result_business = GetBusiness($con, $email);
$json['result'] = "Success";
$json['message'] = "Successfully registered the Business";          
$json["uid"] = $result_business["id"];
$json["business"]["name"] = $result_business["name"];
$json["business"]["email"] = $result_business["email"];
```

but for even if the data are inserted successfully the part of $result_business is null, why I get null? I my $query typed wrong?

thank you

Comment: Can you dump $result_arr in your function ? Before return : `print_r($result_arr)`. What does your browser say ?

Comment: I call my php from android app and there I get with print_r the data but the json object has null

Comment: The format of the array I get with print_r is like Array
(
   [0] => 58
   [B_ID] => 58
   [1] => 1
   [BCAT_ID] => 1
   [2] => Xelona
   [B_NAME] => Xelona
), how to access such table?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, your function `GetBusiness` returns a multi-dimensionnal array, you can use this one instead :

```
function GetBusiness($con, $email)
{
    $query = "SELECT * from Business WHERE B_EMAIL ='".$email."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    return mysqli_fetch_array($res);
}
```

Also, you must use the MySQL columns that you selected to access the data of the rowset. Something like

```
$json["uid"] = $result_business["B_ID"];
$json["business"]["name"] = $result_business["B_NAME"];
```

Comment: i still get Register Response: [{"result":"Success","message":"Successfully registered the Business","uid":null,"business":{"name":null,"email":null}}]